# Defining Set Packing using MathProg

Tags: ampl, glpk, mathprog

For someone with zero experience, this can be very confusing.

How do I define the Set Packing problem as seen in [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing) as a MathProg program, to be later ran in the GLPK tool?

Intution alone would lead me into something like this:

```
var x

maximize SetPacking :
 sum {s in Subsets} x
s.t.         ??              //x is an integer 0 or 1
s.t.         ??              //amount of x <=1
end;
```

But its logic is obviously wrong and I can't even finish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can formulate the set packing problem in [AMPL](http://www.ampl.com) (and MathProg which is based on a subset of AMPL) as follows:

```
set U; # universe
set S; # subsets
set Members{S}; # members of subsets

# every set is either in the set packing or not
var x{S} binary;

# maximize the total number of subsets
maximize NumSets: sum{s in S} x[s];

# selected sets have to be pairwise disjoint
s.t. Disjoint{e in U}: sum{s in S: e in Members[s]} x[s] <= 1;
```

Note that you have to introduce indexed set `Members` with each element `Members[s]`representing members of subset `s`. This is the only difference from the algebraic formulation.